# Can't find Query String Parameters in Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome

I'm just trying to write a program to scrape from a website and I'm trying to set the parameters for my code but I can't find it anywhere. Only "general", "response headers", and "request headers" are showing up.

Comment: Share the request, you have raised?

Comment: Apologies but this is my first project so are you referring to the URL? Or the path?

Comment: you can check the query in payload tab in dev tools

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find it!